# Have Multiple videos on page need to auto play the one of the button clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, video

I have a button that loops for each video, each button is unique to that video. This is the html/php that loops for every video. I need to have on click button, only that video auto plays. Right now all the videos play. I know its how I am calling the button, but not sure how to correct it.

```html
<div id="post_<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
      <div class="modal-dialog  modal-lg vertical-align-center">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/modal-close-x.png" /></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          <video id="video_<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" controls>
            <source src="<?php echo $modal_contents; ?>" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
              <br />
                <div class="row clearfix">
                  <div class="col-md-5 modal-logos"><?php MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'third-image', NULL,  'post-third-image-full img-responsive'); ?></div>
                  <div class="col-md-4 modal-logos"><?php MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'sub-branding', NULL,  'post-sub-branding-full img-responsive'); ?></div>
                </div>     
              </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<button class="btn btn-prod-spec" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#post_<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">View Demo</button>
```

```js
$("button.btn").click(function() {
    var videoid = $('video').closest('video').attr('id');
    alert(videoid);
    $('video').trigger("play");
});
```

Comment: are you implying one clicks play every video and you need separate buttons for separate videos ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that even though you get a video's id -

```
var videoid = $('video').closest('video').attr('id');
```

you are not playing that video, but using a selector `$('video')` that gets all the videos -

```
$('video').trigger("play");
```

The way I would do this, is to add a `data-video` to your button, that is the `id` of your `video` -

```
<button class="btn btn-prod-spec" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-video="#video_<?php echo $post->ID; ?> data-target="#post_<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">View Demo</button>
```

and now your javascript could be something like -

```
$("button.btn").click(function() {
    var videoid = $(this).data('video');
    $(videoid).trigger("play");
});
```

Comment: That works, I know it was something simple I was just missing. Thank you!

Comment: Luvin' the informative answer Sean. Sure as heck beats "Try this" ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes I agree, this was straight to the point, I understood what was needed, and it solved the issue perfectly.

Comment: @Anthony that's what Stack's really all about ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Exactly, I got the help that was needed, I have learned from someone else, and now I know how to solve these issues in the future, and this should help others that may need help. By the way.... Happy New Year!

Comment: @Anthony Thanks, Happy New Year to you also.